# Get file from Url or path?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

*I have integrated `UIDocumentPickerDelegate` or `UIDocumentMenuDelegate`,* I have an issue to get the file from URL or DocumentPicker. How can I solve this issue in iOS swift?

Comment: what issue you getting, write here.

Comment: I get file url from UIDocumentPickerDelegate but i need to get file.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your relevant code (as text) and clearly show where you need help.

Comment: What kind of file ? What is your solution so far ?

Comment: I need to get file like .pdf, .txt, .apk, etc. @Roy

Comment: func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        let cico = url as URL
        print("The Url is : \(cico)")

Comment: UIDocumentPicker will returns you the file URL, from that URL you needs to create the file or download the file from that URL your self.

Comment: How can create the file or download the file from url in iOS swift? @VanditMehta

Comment: like, if URL of image then you should write,     UIImage *receipt = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:url.path];

Comment: Yes, I know this way but How can get file from this way in iOS? @VanditMehta

Comment: I don't know if this comment help you or not but I think when you get file url, you need to show that url data in web view. because web view support all kind of data to show.

Comment: Yes, i know but in my case i can send file in chat. @bittu

Comment: Then I think as @VanditMehta suggest you can create image type object for image, audio type object for audio etc and send it over chat. Other than that I don't think there is any other option.

Comment: Any success on this ?

Answer (score 5):

> You can get file easily like,

If you need to get image

```
    @IBAction func btn_Handler_iCloud(_ sender: Any) {
        let doc = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeImage)], in: .import)
        doc.delegate = self
        doc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(doc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urls[0])
        imageview_Buaty.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting document URL or data from UIDocumentPickerViewController:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) { 
    // Available from iOS 8.0 to iOS 11.0
    self.handleFileSelection(inUrl: url)// Here url is document's URL
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    // Available from iOS 11.0
    self.handleFileSelection(inUrl: urls.first!)  // Here urls is array of URLs
}

private func handleFileSelection(inUrl:URL) -> Void {
    do { 
     // inUrl is the document's URL
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: inUrl) // Getting file data here
    } catch {
        dLog(message: "document loading error")
    }
}
```